# Dynamic insert into DB

Tags: php, database, postgresql

i'm creating a simple web app which a form to insert data in DB ( Postgres).

I have this tables:

> prenotazione (id,nome_rich,cogn_rich,email_rich,oggetto_rich)
>
> interni (id,nome_int,cogn_int,email_int)
>
> esterni (id,nome_est,cogn_est,email_est)

Now about the tables "interni" and "esterni" the users should choose how many data want to insert, so i have implemented a dynamic form:

**index.php

```
<div id="start">
    <div id="first">
      Nome:<input type="text" name="iname[]" size="20"><br> 
      Cognome: <input type="text" name="isurname[]" size="20"><br> 
      Email: <input type="email" name="iemail[]" size="20"><br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <b> Numero partecipanti interni:</b>
  <input type="text" id="n1" value="1"><br>
  <button><a href="#" id="add1">Aggiungi partecipante</a></button>
  </div>
```

**input.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$testo = $_POST['testo'];

//inserting data order
$query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione (id,nome_rich, cogn_rich, email_rich,oggetto_rich) VALUES (1,'$name','$surname', '$email','$testo')";
//execute the query here
$result = pg_query($conn, $query1 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource
// Interni
$query = "";
if( !empty( $_POST['iname'] ) ) {

    foreach( $_POST['iname'] as $key => $iname ) {

        $isurname = empty( $_POST[$key]['isurname'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['isurname'];
        $iemail = empty( $_POST[$key]['iemail'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['iemail'];
        $query .= " ( '$iname', '$isurname', '$iemail' ) ";
    }
}
if( !empty( $query ) ) {

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO interni (nome_int, cogn_int, email_int) VALUES ".$query;
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query2 );
```

The problem is that when they try to insert data into "interni" and the data are more than one, they can't and i receive an error. ( basically the table "interni" is empty when they try to insert more than one ).
How can i solve the problem?
Thanks you all

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Missing comma between VALUES.

Comment: @KMS Basically i can't insert multiple data, because they result concatenating. I receive error in :
$result = pg_query($conn, $query2 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński 
Exactly I thought this was the problem, but I find it difficult to understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing comma in between VALUES.

This is what you are executing: `INSERT INTO table VALUES (stuff) (stuff2) (stuff3)`

Correct is: `INSERT INTO table VALUES (stuff), (stuff2), (stuff3)`

Fix:

```
    $iemail = empty( $_POST[$key]['iemail'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['iemail'];
    if($query != "") {
      $query .= ",";
    }
    $query .= " ( '$iname', '$isurname', '$iemail' ) ";
```